# How to perform an action when tab bar tapped?

Tags: swift

I want to present interstitial ad when a specific `UITabBarItem` tapped. is it possible to handle functions when `UITabBarItem` tapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Any time a tab bar button is pressed a segue between view controllers is initiated. So, any time a tab bar button is pressed, the prepare for segue function is called.